# How do i get user_likes permission from Facebook developers?

Tags: javascript, c#, facebook

I am developing one website in asp.net, it has an option called login through Facebook, and it has to allow login if and only if a user like my page on facebook. I have done all the procedures to get user_likes permission from the Facebook developer, even though if I fill all the procedures in user_likes page submit button is not activating, Can anyone help in this regard? 
This is what have done in my code:
HTML source code:

```
<script>
(function(d) {
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
} (document));
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '****************', 
        channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel', 
        status: true, 
        cookie: true, 
        xfbml: true  
    });  
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {          
            FB.api({
    method:     "pages.isFan",
    page_id:        '****************',
},  function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if(response){
            window.location = "Default2.aspx";
        } else {
            window.location = "Default3.aspx";     
        }
      });       
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
    $("#auth-logoutlink").click(function () { FB.logout(function () { window.location.reload(); }); });
}
    </script>
```

Comment: _"I am developing one website in asp.net"_ Then have some code on your computer right? Post that code as [mcve] here.

Comment: incentivizing liking a page is not allowed and you will not get user_likes approved for this, obviously. you must read the platform policy before creating any app.

Answer (score 0):

the like option on objects and photos, were disabled by facebook in 2016, discussed with them (they were abused too). The user_likes option allows you to retrieve all the pages liked by the user.
In this case, you would have to use the facebook-like plugin. You can find more information about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/like-button

I hope I've helped!